# How to queue hosted services in .netcore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-queue, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have two background services A and B. Service A grab the token and save it in the cache which is required to run service B.

What I want to know, is there any way where I can force to run service A first and then service B?

I have looked into Queued background tasks but I dont think it is what I need.

Comment: No. All hosted services are immediately started at app start. You cannot specify a start order. However, each hosted service should be entirely self-contained. If one relies on another, then you've built them wrong.

Comment: Basically I need to run controller every second as soon as app starts, what you recommend?

Comment: They dont depend on each other but they depend on result, service A grabs the token and service B run the controller which make further calls to api which needs authorization header

Comment: That's depending on each other. If service B needs something that service A produces, then service B *also* needs to produce that. It cannot rely on service A.

Comment: is there a way to run code in controller every second once app is loaded?

Comment: No. That's what a hosted service is for.